# Service not getting exposed Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose

I have deployed this app [here](https://github.com/kaleidos-ventures/taiga-docker) to kubernetes and finally got all the containers running in kubernetes after struggling a bit with the volumes. This is the `kubectl get svc` output.

```
kubernetes      ClusterIP      10.116.0.1      <none>          443/TCP          95m
taiga-gateway   LoadBalancer   10.116.10.159   35.1xx.5x.2xx   9000:32087/TCP   91m
```

```
taiga-async-6c7d9dbd7b-hl4lh             1/1     Running   1          91m

taiga-async-rabbitmq-86979cf759-x2lrx    1/1     Running   0          91m

taiga-back-cbd4b68f4-fbwx9               1/1     Running   0          24s

taiga-db-cb496d58c-mdsfw                 1/1     Running   0          80m

taiga-events-74f494df97-hqxpt            1/1     Running   0          91m

taiga-events-rabbitmq-7f558ddf88-rz6nz   1/1     Running   4          91m

taiga-front-5487d594b8-6vml8             1/1     Running   0          13m

taiga-gateway-7487554979-2d9ct           1/1     Running   0          44m

taiga-protected-7794949d49-bws46         1/1     Running   0          91m](url)
```

However, I see that the `taiga-back` servive is unstable. It keeps giving this error. This is the cluster endpoint IP.

```
        Is the server running on host "3x.1x3.88.xx6" and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

and I am not able to access the application from outside.

```
kubernetes      ClusterIP      10.116.0.1      <none>          443/TCP          109m
taiga-gateway   LoadBalancer   10.116.10.159   3x.x8x.5x.2x3   9000:32087/TCP   105m
```

I have provided my cluster endpoint IP here as the connection point for the `DB` as I did when deploying this application on a regular Machine using `docker-compose`.

```yaml
              value: "True"
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: taiga
            - name: POSTGRES_HOST
              value: 34.123.88.206
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              value: taiga
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: taiga
            - name: RABBITMQ_PASS
              value: taiga
            - name: RABBITMQ_USER
              value: taiga
            - name: TAIGA_SECRET_KEY
              value: taiga-back-secret-key
            - name: TAIGA_SITES_DOMAIN
              value: 34.123.88.206:9000
            - name: TAIGA_SITES_SCHEME
              value: http
            - name: TAIGA_SUBPATH
          image: taigaio/taiga-back:latest
          name: taiga-back
```

However, it is different from the loadbalancer's IP. I am a bit confused about this. Is this the reason why I am not able to access this? or is it something I missed entirely? Please guide a little.

Comment: I'd expect `$POSTGRES_HOST` to match the Kubernetes Service name for your database (`taiga-db`?) and not an external IP address.

Comment: What taigia-db if not a DB service?

Comment: If you only have the two things in the `kubectl get svc` output then you are missing several Service definitions.  Anything that can receive network requests needs a Service; it's not necessarily a bad practice to make sure every Pod is associated with a Service (if you use the Istio service mesh, it requires this).

Comment: @DavidMaze I created all the services and now it is accessible. There are other issues, but those would be for another question. Thanks for the hint.